# data alignment under Linux/IA32

Tags: c, struct, x86, memory-alignment, abi

I meet two structs:

```
struct s1{
  int i;
  int j;
  char c;}

struct s2{
  int i;
  char c1;
  int j;
  char c2;}
```

the textbook says c in S1 only occupies 1 byte,whereas c2 in S2 occupies 4 bytes, why is this?
Is it because c1 has to occupy 4 bytes, and they have the same type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 bytes of padding after `s1::c`, same as after `s2::c1`, in the i386 System V ABI's struct layout rules.  (And most normal ABIs.)

The total struct size has to be a multiple of its `alignof()` for arrays to work: structs in contiguous memory, each one taking `sizeof(struct s1)`, but also the start of each struct being aligned so that the `int` members are aligned.

Look at the `sizeof()` and `alignof()` of both types, and of int vs. char.  sizeof(char) = 1 as defined by ISO C, and in i386 SysV, sizeof(int) = alignof(int) = 4.

If you had a `struct { char foo[8]; char c; };` then it's total size *would* only be 9 bytes, because alignof(char) = 1.

Comment: I understand that s1 should have 3 more bytes like this: struct s1 a[4] . But if I dont declare a, is it still the same？I meet this in CS:APP. Here is the quote: If we pack this structure into 9 bytes, we can still satisfy the alignment requirements
for fields i and j by making sure that the starting address of the structure satisfies
a 4-byte alignment requiremen.

Comment: So the total size of an struct should always be a multiple of its alignment, no matter whether you declare an array of this struct.